# [KIK MESSENGER]Configure Bot, JSON give a suggestion

Tags: json, kik

my question is , how do i add something like a suggestion, here is how it works

User : suggestions
Bot : We're happy to hear that you have a suggestion! Please type your suggestion below
User : Pleaz add sumthin cool 
Bot: Thanks for suggesting!
[ Bot Sends the suggestion to my kik pringlejingle]

id like to know how go do this using JSON

Answer (score 0):

Is 'pringlejingle' a chat bot? You won't be able to send a message directly to your user account, but you could build a chatbot to do this.

Have a look at https://dev.kik.com/ for the API reference. There's also a python sample bot available on github (linked in the above dev docs).

You can also reach out to bots@kik.com for development help.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you first need to get the unique chatid of pringlejingle username.

To do this, send a message (say **Hi**) to your bot from pringlejingle username.

Your bot would receive a json object something like this:

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "chatId": "0ee6d46753bfa6ac2f089149959363f3f59ae62b10cba89cc426490ce38ea92d",
            "id": "0115efde-e54b-43d5-873a-5fef7adc69fd",
            "type": "text",
            "from": "pringlejingle",
            "participants": ["pringlejingle"],
            "body": "Hi",
            "timestamp": 1439576628405,
            "readReceiptRequested": true,
            "mention": null,
            "metadata": null,
            "chatType": "direct",
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above json object, `0ee6d46753bfa6ac2f089149959363f3f59ae62b10cba89cc426490ce38ea92d` is the chatid and it will be obviously different for your username (pringlejingle).

Get this chatid.

And make two http post requests with json objects like these:

```
{
    'messages': [
        {
            'body': 'Thanks for suggesting!', 
            'to': <username of the sender>, 
            'type': 'text', 
            'chatId': <chat id of the sender>
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    'messages': [
        {
            'body': <suggestion of the sender>, 
            'to': 'pringlejingle', 
            'type': 'text', 
            'chatId': <chat id of pringlejingle>
        }
    ]
}
```

- In the chatflow, make a database to store suggestions information (username, chatid, etc.).
- When a request for suggestion is sent by a user, add the information to the database.
- When a message is received to the bot, check from the database if the user has previously requested for suggestion. If found in the database, process the suggestion chatflow.

Here is an example of using json object in Python:

```
import json
import sys
import requests
import sqlite3

def postdata(username=None,chatid=None,message=None):
    botusername=<USERNAMEOFYOURBOT>
    botapikey=<APIKEYOFYOURBOT>
    r=requests.post(
        'https://api.kik.com/v1/message',
        auth=(botusername,botapikey),
        headers={
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data=json.dumps({
            'messages': [
                {
                    'body': message, 
                    'to': username, 
                    'type': 'text', 
                    'chatId': chatid
                }
            ]
        })
    )
    return r

form=json.loads(sys.stdin.read())
conn=sqlite3.connect('suggestionsdatabase.db')
c=conn.cursor()

# to create tables if tables were not found
if ('suggestions',) not in list(c.execute("SELECT NAME FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")):
    c.execute('CREATE suggestions (username TEXT, chatid TEXT)')
    conn.commit()
if ('pringlejingle-chatid',) not in list(c.execute("SELECT NAME FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")):
    c.execute('CREATE pringlejingle-chatid (chatid TEXT)')
    conn.commit()

# to store the chatid of pringlejingle
if form['messages'][0]['from']=='pringlejingle':
    c.execute('INSERT INTO pringlejingle-chatid VALUES (?)',(form['messages'][0]['chatId'],))
    conn.commit()
    outputmessage='Your chat id is successfully saved in the database.'
    postdata(username=form['messages'][0]['from'],chatid=form['messages'][0]['chatId'],message=outputmessage)

#processing the suggestions chatflow.
checksuggestions=list(c.execute('SELECT * FROM suggestions WHERE username=? AND chatid=?',(form['messages'][0]['from'],form['messages'][0]['chatId'],)))
if len(checksuggestions)!=0:
    postdata(username=form['messages'][0]['from'],chatid=form['messages'][0]['chatId'],message='Thanks for suggesting!')
    pringlejinglechatid=list(c.execute('SELECT * FROM pringlejingle-chatid'))
    formattedsuggestion='Suggestion from '+form['messages'][0]['from']+':\n\n'+form['messages'][0]['body']+'\n-------end of the suggestion-------'
    postdata(username='pringlejingle',chatid=pringlejinglechatid,message=formattedsuggestion)

elif form['messages'][0]['body'].lower()=='suggestions':
    outputmessage="We're happy to hear that you have a suggestion!"
    c.execute('INSERT INTO suggestions VALUES (?,?)',(form['messages'][0]['from'],form['messages'][0]['chatId'],))
    conn.commit()
    postdata(username=form['messages'][0]['from'],chatid=form['messages'][0]['chatId'],message=outputmessage)
else:
    outputmessage='I am not yet programmed for this input.'
    postdata(username=form['messages'][0]['from'],chatid=form['messages'][0]['chatId'],message=outputmessage)
```

Firstly, a message from pringlejingle is to be sent to the bot, so that it could store the chat id of pringlejingle in the database. Once this is done, the bot can process 'suggestions' chatflow.